# Explicit jsonb type cast in Squeryl

Tags: postgresql, scala, jdbc, squeryl

I'm using Squeryl 0.9.5-7 and Postgres 9.4 with jsonb datatype and want to insert some data:

```
case class Log(id: String, meta: String) //meta will contain json
val logs = table[Log]
logs.insert(Log(randomId, "{\"Hi\": \"I'm a json!\"}"))
```

But got a typecast error that says *"Column meta has jsonb type but expression has character varying type. Rewrite expression or convert it's type."*

How can I explicitly cast my `String` field into `jsonb` so that raw sql-parameter will look like `?::jsonb`?

And then, it's interesting how to write json-queries such as `@>` or `->>` with Squeryl?

Comment: have you found a satisfying solution?

Answer (score 3):

I found a better way, that doesn't require to create a CAST in the database.

If you're using squeryl 0.9.6, you can add an explicit cast in your schema which tells squeryl to explicitly cast your string into a jsonb.

```
on(logs)(s => declare(
   s.meta is (dbType("jsonb").explicitCast) // enables explicit casting into jsonb
 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

With Squeryl 0.9.6 you can register support for your own custom types.  Here's [an example](https://github.com/max-l/squeryl-extended-field-types-example/blob/master/src/main/scala/example/MyCustomTypes.scala).  For non standard operators, take a look at [custom functions](http://squeryl.org/custom-functions.html)

Comment: can you actually implement the cast, i.e. ::json just with custom types?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with postgres 9.4, reading works fine as a Squeryl String but inserting fails with:

> ERROR: column "****" is of type json but expression is of type
>   character varying [error]   Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the
>   expression. [error]   Position: 166 [error] errorCode: 0, sqlState:
>   42804

So, the solution I found is to create a 'AS ASSIGNMENT' cast in my postgres database and that does the trick:

```
CREATE CAST(VARCHAR AS JSON)
WITH INOUT
AS ASSIGNMENT
```